# Prevent any program from forcefully ending a my running programs

Tags: windows

Is there a way to prevent any program (including task manager) from ending any of my running programs?

Comment: Why?  What circumstance would that be useful to you?

Answer (score 2):

No. The operating system has to be able to manage the software running inside it, which includes the ability to stop processes.

The applications that try to protect themselves from closure by the OS are most often malicious software. Most legitimate software does not require this excessive security, and if it does, it is written to run directly on the hardware itself rather than requiring a host operating system.